# Matrix multiplication of a sparse SciPy matrix with two NumPy vectors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I want to compute the quadratic form `x^T A y`, where `x` and `y` are NumPy vectors, and I have stored `A` as a SciPy `csc_matrix` for efficiency.

It seems that one way to perform the computation is

```
(x * A).dot(y)
```

since SciPy uses `*` for matrix products, and NumPy uses `.dot` instead.

While this approach gives me the correct answer, it seems rather counter-intuitive to me, and I wonder if there's a more readable/efficient approach?

Comment: why dont you use [numpy matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)?

Comment: @hadik Ew, don't recommend that.

Comment: If you are on a recent Python/NumPy version, you can write `x @ A @ y`.

Comment: Why does it look counter-intuitive? Are you expecting the final output to be sparsey?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Ah, actually I'm still on Python 2.7...

Comment: @Divakar As @if.... mentioned in his answer, I think that having `*` can be confusing if I didn't realize `A` is actually a sparse matrix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul Panzer said, `x @ A @ y` is most readable and works as expected (requires Python 3.5+ and NumPy 1.10+).

SciPy uses `dot` for matrix multiplication too, in their own examples on [sparse matrices page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). So you can use dot consistently like

```
x.dot(A.dot(y))
```

or `A.dot(y).dot(x)` although the latter is harder to read because x is out of place.

The only reason you can't use `x.dot(A).dot(y)` is that NumPy does not understand sparse matrices, so the dot method  of `x` is unsuitable for multiplication by a sparse matrix.

Although SciPy sparse matrices  interpret `x * A` and `A * y` as matrix multiplication, I prefer to never use that option, because of the risk of wrong operation if A changes to a dense matrix for some reason. It doesn't look like this usage of `*` is promoted in SciPy documentation; all examples use `dot`.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I tried `x.dot(A).dot(y)` initially and got the wrong answer, but I didn't think of `x.dot(A.dot(y))`.

Comment: Just a follow-up question though: could I compute `x^\ts A` using `.dot()` when `A` is a sparse matrix? Thanks!

Comment: As `A.T.dot(x)`. I assume A is 2d array and x is 1d array. Transpose does not affect 1d arrays, they don't have two axes to swap. So only A needs to be transposed to be moved to the other side. The output is a 1d array, so again the concept of transpose doesn't apply to it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!